# Python | matplotlib > Cómo separar valores en gráfica de tiempo y unir los valores similares

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

En la siguiente gráfica no he encontrado lograr como separar los valores de un mismo referente y graficarlos uniéndolos por una linea.

Me explico mejor acá:

Tengo mi siguiente input:

```
Fecha,Pais,count
"20/05/2017",Brazil,1
"20/05/2017",China,821
"20/05/2017",Czechia,31
"20/05/2017",France,1
"20/05/2017","Republic of Korea",1
"21/05/2017",Argentina,5
"21/05/2017",Australia,2
"21/05/2017",China,3043
"21/05/2017",Denmark,1
"21/05/2017",Egypt,1
...
..
.
```

Ya tengo importado el array, convirtiendo todos los valores, tanto de fecha como String e integer.

```
DatetimeIndex(['2017-05-20', '2017-05-20', '2017-05-20', '2017-05-20',
               '2017-05-20', '2017-05-21', '2017-05-21', '2017-05-21',
               '2017-05-21', '2017-05-21', '2017-05-21', '2017-05-21',
               '2017-05-21', '2017-05-21', '2017-05-21', '2017-05-21',
               '2017-05-21', '2017-05-21', '2017-05-21', '2017-05-21',
               '2017-05-22', '2017-05-22', '2017-05-22', '2017-05-22',
               '2017-05-22', '2017-05-22', '2017-05-22', '2017-05-22',
               '2017-05-22', '2017-05-22', '2017-05-22', '2017-05-22',
               '2017-05-22', '2017-05-22', '2017-05-22', '2017-05-22'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
['Brazil' 'China' 'Czechia' 'France' 'Republic of Korea' 'Argentina'
 'Australia' 'China' 'Denmark' 'Egypt' 'France' 'Hungary' 'Netherlands'
 'Oman' 'Republic of Korea' 'Russia' 'Slovak Republic' 'Taiwan' 'Ukraine'
 'United Arab Emirates' 'Argentina' 'Brazil' 'China' 'Czechia' 'Ecuador'
 'France' 'Germany' 'India' 'Latvia' 'Liberia' 'Pakistan' 'Peru'
 'Republic of Korea' 'Russia' 'Taiwan' 'Ukraine']
['1' '821' '31' '1' '1' '5' '2' '3043' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1'
 '3' '48' '1' '2' '1' '3759' '79' '2' '1' '3' '1' '192' '1' '1' '1' '1' '2'
 '1' '1']
```

Ya tengo la gráfica también:

[image: figura 1]

Lo que no he logrado es unir las lineas de cada país, lo que estoy logrando es solo plotear cada valor, pero no estoy ploteando con base al string del país.

acá mi código:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from  matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, DayLocator, AutoDateLocator, AutoDateFormatter
import datetime


locator = DayLocator()
formatter = AutoDateFormatter(locator)

date, country, count = np.loadtxt("72hcountcountry.csv",
                                  delimiter=',',
                                  unpack=True,
                                  dtype='string',
                                  skiprows=1)

date = np.char.replace (date, '"', '')
country = np.char.replace (country, '"', '')
date2 = pd.to_datetime(date)

print date2
print country 
print count

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot_date(date2, count)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
ax.autoscale_view()

ax.grid(True)
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

**Como grafico una linea por cada país que tenga datos en las fechas?**

[Update]

Duda, cuando extraes el csv, con parse_dates, como puedo cambiar el formato de la fecha?

En el csv viene nativo de esta manera:

```
"05/06/2017","Republic of Korea",3
```

No se, pero curioso, cuando estábamos en mayo 2x, obtenía bien el mes y el día, pero cuando cambio a junio (imagino que del 1 al 12, como esta en esta ejemplo), me esta cambiando el día por el mes, para lo cual yo estaba convirtiendo forzando el formato con:

```
pd.to_datetime(date, format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

Puedo hacerlo directo al leer del csv? o lo cambiarías después ya en el arreglo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que usas Pandas explotalo, es muy simple usando `groupby` para agrupar por paises, hecho esto basta con graficar cada grupo:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import cm
from  matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, DayLocator, AutoDateLocator, AutoDateFormatter


df = pd.read_csv("72hcountcountry.csv", delimiter=',', parse_dates = ['Fecha', 'count'])
grupos = df.groupby(['Pais'])


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
color=iter(cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0,1,len(grupos))))

for nombre, grupo in grupos:
    ax.plot_date(x = grupo['Fecha'], y = grupo['count'], color = next(color), marker='o', ls = 'solid', label=nombre)

locator = DayLocator()
formatter = AutoDateFormatter(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
ax.autoscale_view()

ax.grid(True)
fig.autofmt_xdate()

ax.margins(0.05)

box = ax.get_position()
ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.8, box.height])
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))

plt.show()
```

Obtenemos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: **Excelente, funciona bien, no había tomando en cuenta llevarlo por Pandas.** Ahora tengo un problema con fechas, mirar abajo.

Comment: Gracias @FJSevilla

Puedes parsearlo directamente usando el parámetro dayfirst : df = pd.read_csv("72hcountcountry.csv", delimiter=',', parse_dates = ['Fecha', 'count'], dayfirst=True).

Comment: Muchas gracias @FJSevilla